# I can serialize an object perfectly... but I can't re-deserialize moments after serialization

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I'm not sure if my problem is with me or if the problem is with Newtonsoft.Json.

I've been stuck on deserializing an object for a while now, and have even tried a desperate attempt below:

```
        ApplianceBulkRequest test1 = new ApplianceBulkRequest();
        test1.UserID = "user1234";
        string test1JSON = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test1);
        // LETS UNDO WHAT I JUST DID ABOVE:
        ApplianceBulkRequest bulkRequest = (ApplianceBulkRequest)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(test1JSON);
```

The code above does nothing but return this:

`A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in LightWeightConsole`

What could be causing an invalid cast exception here?

I just dont even know why I'm using a 3rd party library for JSON like it's 1999...

Comment: Try as `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApplianceBulkRequest>(test1JSON);`

Comment: @BenKnoble No, `DeserializeObject` returns `JObject or JArray`. But `DeserializeObject<T>` returns `T`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The non-generic `DeserializeObject` method will not magically find a type to map your object to... you must use the generic version: `DeserializeObject<ApplianceBulkRequest>(test1JSON)`